# Calculate aperture size in plate where water falls on, at a certain water flow

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I have a construction where water falls on/through a perforated plate via a waterfall (see image below). The plate needs to evenly distibute the water over the underlying structure. My question is how to calculate the hole sizes (or total hole area) in the plate, so the water distributes evenly and does not overflow? Flow rate coming from the waterfall is 30m3/h, some dimensions are in the image below.

Hopefully someone can help me, thanks.

[image]

Comment: The effect of the sum of the holes will not be the same as 1 large hole of the same area - I would have the plate removable and go by trial and error - sizes of hole etc By the way are the dimensions metres or centimetres or millimeters - you hint at metres as you use m3, but that seems very unlikely...